# Convert C++ dll method to C# with const char *s2 = NULL

Tags: c#

Can someone explain me how to convert this C++ API into a method which can be called by C# using interop?

```
__EXTERN_C __declspec(dllexport) LONG __stdcall Method1(char *s1,WORD w2, const char *s2 = NULL)
```

to call by C#

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("DllName.dll", EntryPoint = "Method1")]
public static extern int Method1(String s1, ushort w2, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String s2);
```

I've tried this but it seems not correct. Thanks

Comment: This depends on what the API does with `s1`. Since it's not declared `const` it may be designed to modify its input, in which case you'd need an `[In, Out] StringBuilder`. What's not right in any case is the return type (use `long`, not `int`) and the fact that you're missing `CharSet = CharSet.Ansi` in the `DllImport` (since these do not appear to be Unicode strings).

Comment: The s1 is for input only, i have modified as below:
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("DllName.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "Method1")] public static extern long Method1(String s1, ushort w2, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String s2);

But still it is not work, but when i call it using C++, it is working.

Comment: @JeroenMostert [`LONG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types#LONG) is `int`. So would be `long`.